# Vuetify Pagination Data-table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

If you use `:pagination.sync="pagination"` to control the number of items being displayed on the screen. Can you still use their built in `pagination.sortBy` or will you have to build your own algorithm for it.

Here is vuetify's codepen of what I want to do minus the personalized sorting part: https://codepen.io/BrandiW/pen/zmEvyg?&editors=101

Comment: your code pen is empty

Comment: Thank you, I just changed it!

Answer (score 0):

> :pagination.page.sync="pagination"

if you sync that way, vue by-default column sort and search will work as usual. though pagination watch call all time for search and column sort, you have to handle it: fetch data needed or not